# Having an issue in adding new records and accessing records

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been testing out my code and I found some issues that I'm unsure of how to fix. It seems that whenever I'm adding a new record, the record isn't really being added, I've tested this out by having whenever a record is added, the program is to show all of the records and it looks like its just showing the record that I hardcoded into the program. I'm using a linked list to do so but I'm not sure that I'm implementing it right.

**EDIT:** I've made a few changes, one of the remaining issues is the add. When I made the change to the main program

> > Struct Student student1, tempStudent; 
> >     The program went into an infinite loop when add was selected and the first entry was input.

.h file:

```
#ifndef SLIST_H
#define SLIST_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    int ID;
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
    string phoneNumber;
    string major;
    float GPA;
    int year;
    int month;
    int date;
    string address;
};

class Node
{
public:
    struct Student data;
    Node *next;
    Node();
    struct Student GetData();
    void SetData(struct Student);
    friend class LinkedList;
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    int length;
    Node *currentPos;
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    int LengthIs();
    void MakeEmpty();
    void AddToTail(struct Student);
    void AddToHead(struct Student);
    int SearchByID(struct Student);
    void DeleteFromHead();
    void DeleteFromTail();
    void Delete(int);
    Node GetNext();
    bool IsLast();
    void Reset();
    void PrintAll(int, string);
};


void LinkedList::AddToTail(struct Student item)
{
    Node *ptr = new Node();
    ptr->SetData(item);
    if (length == 0)
    {
        tail = ptr;
        head = ptr;
        length++;
        return;
    }
    tail->next = ptr;
    tail = ptr;
    length++;

}

void LinkedList::AddToHead(struct Student item)
{
    Node *ptr = new Node;
    ptr->SetData(item);
    ptr->next = head;
    head = ptr;
    if (length == 0) tail = ptr;
    length++;
}


#endif
```

main program:

```
#include "slist.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LinkedList students;
    int choice = 1;
    Student student1, tempStudent;
    Node student1Node;
    int ret;
    student1.ID = 12345678;
    student1.firstName = "Daenerys";
    student1.lastName = "Targaryen";
    student1.phoneNumber = "111-123-1234";
    student1.major = "PScience";
    student1.GPA = 3.9;
    student1.year = 2000;
    student1.month = 11;
    student1.date = 30;
    student1.address = "1234 Harpy Way Mereen, OK 74701";

    students.AddToHead(student1);

    while (choice != 6)
    {
        cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
        cout << "1: Add a student record." << endl;
        cout << "2: Remove a student record." << endl;
        cout << "3: List all students." << endl;
        cout << "4: List the student(s) by major or by ID." << endl;
        cout << "5: Order the list." << endl;
        cout << "6: Exit!" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Make your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Warning: there's a lot of data entry. Try to keep up with what you're entering."
                     << endl;
                cout << "Please enter in the student's ID, first name, last name, phone number and major ON SEPARATE LINES";
                cout << endl;
                cin >> tempStudent.ID;
                cin >> tempStudent.firstName;
                cin >> tempStudent.lastName;
                cin >> tempStudent.phoneNumber;
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin, tempStudent.major);
                cout << "Almost done! Enter the student's gpa, birth year, birth month (IN DIGITS!!!), birth date, and address ON SEPARATE LINES.";
                cout << endl;
                cin >> tempStudent.GPA;
                cin >> tempStudent.year;
                cin >> tempStudent.month;
                cin >> tempStudent.date;
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin, tempStudent.address);

                students.AddToHead(tempStudent);
                cout << "Student entry added!" << endl;
                students.PrintAll(-1, "");
                break;
```

Comment: `if (current->data.major != major) ;` That semicolon is a very bad idea.

Comment: Recommend reworking the question to focus on exactly one problem. Recommend starting with the add and removing all of the code unrelated to demonstrating that the add does not work. Often at this point you have so little code that the answer jumps right out at you, but if not post that little bit of code that's left and someone will probably have an answer for you much faster that if they have to wade through all the existing code and duplicate all of your inputs.

Comment: `Student` is a class, so don't declare `struct Student student1;`. Just put `Student student1;`

Comment: It looks like for the search, that the semicolon was the issue. It's now showing the hardcoded entry.

Comment: I did as barmak had suggested on student and now the program is going into an infinte loop when add is chosen and on the first entry of the record (when you enter the first name). the output is -1.07674e+008 -858993460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an input error, it's not because you removed the wrong `struct` keyword

`cin >> tempStudent.ID;` will fail if you input a non-integer and causes the infinite loop. You must check if the input succeeded, and clear the input if it failed.

```
//cin >> tempStudent.ID; <- remove this line

while(true) //<- replace with this
{
    cout << "id: ";
    if( (cin >> tempStudent.ID) )
        break;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(0x1000, '\n');
}
```

You might want to add a function to do the same input error check for other integer inputs.

Change the other cases of `cin.ignore()` to

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(0x1000, '\n');
```

`cin.clear()` is recommended if you are expecting integer input and user accidentally enters text.

Comment: I have another question related to this. How can I make sure only the chosen length of the int ID of this structure is accepted? For example, I want to make sure the ID is only 9 digits long, no fewer, no more. How can I do that?

Comment: You can check `if (ID >= 100000000 && ID <= 999999999){...}` and ask the user to input again if input size is wrong. Another caveat is that if user inputs `1234 5678` (blank space in between) then that counts as two inputs, and two `>>` operator are called, `5678` will be assigned to `firstName`. You can use `std::getline(cin, string_id)` which reads the whole line. Then check the string's length, and check each character to validate input.